# Does python's httplib library uses proxy setting from environment variables?

Tags: python, proxy, httplib

I need to know if httplib library in Python will use the "http_proxy" variable set in my Linux OS environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the source code of [Lib/httplib.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py), there is not call to [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) which is the way to get/set environment variables, neither to any sort of environment reference. So the answer seems to be: no.

But you can call [set_tunnel()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection.set_tunnel) using your env vars:

```
from os import environ
from urlparse import urlparse

url = urlparse(environ['http_proxy'])
conn.set_tunnel(url.hostname, url.port)
```

There are other attributes like `url.username` and `url.password`, see [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse).